# Create label in nested containers that are in a tab

Tags: java, containers, codenameone

How can I create a label that is nested inside containers that are in a tab. What I am doing right now causes the app to fail when I run it. Here is my code:

```
protected void beforeMain(Form f) {

   Label Test = new Label("Test it");
   findFamilyMembers(f).addComponent(Test);


}
```

The hierarchy of the containers in the form are as follows:

Main[Form] -> Tabs1[Tabs] -> FirstTab[container] -> PplIcons[container] -> FamilyMembers[container]

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It ok i found what my mistake was. I was creating the label before loading the form in:

```
protected void beforeMain(Form f)
```